# equial height not working properly?

Tags: javascript, css

Hello I have tried doing the equal heights js code but its not working for me somehow,

this is my js fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7tt5xwu/)

I think im missing something with the  classes?
Thanks in advance for any help

this is my html:

```js
// equal heights - plugin 
;(function($) {

    $.fn.equalHeights = function() {
        var maxHeight = 0,
            $this = $(this);

        $this.each( function() {
            var height = $(this).innerHeight();
            if ( height > maxHeight ) { maxHeight = height; }
        });

        return $this.css('height', maxHeight);
    };

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){

    var equaliseMozaic = function(){
        $('.jury-president__block').equalHeights();
        console.log('reset');
    };

    // make mozaic blocks equal heights
 if( $('.jury-president__block').length > 0 ){
        // equalise mozaic blocks
        equaliseMozaic();
        // equalise mozaic blocks on resize
        var throttledequaliseMozaic = _.throttle(equaliseMozaic, 500);
        $(window).resize(throttledequaliseMozaic);
    }
    
});
```

```css
.jury-blocks{}
.jury-president__block{width:100px; display: inline-block; background-color:gray;}
.jury-president__block img {width:50px;}
```

```html
 <div class="jury-blocks">
            <div class="jury-president__block grid-20">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="jury-president__category"> Name<br>erwer</div>
                <div class="jury-president__name"> Name, Juror Company</div>
            </div>
            <div class="jury-president__block grid-20">
                <a href="">
                    <!--- <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" alt=""> --->
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="jury-president__category"> Name</div>
                <div class="jury-president__name"> Name, Juror Company</div>
            </div>
            <div class="jury-president__block grid-20">
                <a href="">
                    <!--- <img src="/assets/images/female-silhouette.jpg" alt=""> --->
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="jury-president__category"> Name</div>
                <div class="jury-president__name"> Name,  Company</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Java?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this seems to make it work:

`.jury-blocks{display:flex;}`

Does this plunk have the behavior you were looking for? http://plnkr.co/edit/mPCw3Firht2lbdEMRCpn?p=preview If not, I can try again.

Additionally, your fiddle did not include jQuery or underscore, both of which appear to be necessary. Once I included those in my plunk, the heights were correct, the divs were just not all positioned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS

> .jury-blocks { display: table; }
>   .jury-president__block{ display:table-cell; vertical-align:top;}

No need of JS